# create header files and run them

Tags: c++, matrix

/***Here i have created a header file to implement matrix representation.But The file doesn't compile and shows the message "The project still doesn't build yet", how to make changes in the code?***/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
public:
  int n_rows, n_columns;
  int **arr;

  Matrix(int rows, int columns)
  {
    srand(time(0));
    n_rows = rows;
    n_columns = columns;

    arr = new int* [rows];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      arr[i] = new int[columns];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        arr[i][j] = ((rand() % 100) - 50);
      }
    }
  }

  ~Matrix(){
    delete [] arr;
  }


  friend Matrix operator+(Matrix const &m1, Matrix const &m2){
    int x, y;
    Matrix newMat(m1.n_rows, m1.n_columns);
    for(int i = 0; i < m1.n_rows; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < m1.n_columns; j++) {
        newMat.arr[i][j] = m1.arr[i][j] + m2.arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    return newMat;
  }

  friend Matrix operator-(Matrix const &m1, Matrix const &m2){
    int x, y;
    Matrix newMat(m1.n_rows, m1.n_columns);
    for(int i = 0; i < m1.n_rows; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < m1.n_columns; j++) {
        newMat.arr[i][j] = m1.arr[i][j] - m2.arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    return newMat;
  }

  friend Matrix operator*(Matrix const &m1, Matrix const &m2) {
    Matrix newMat(m1.n_rows, m1.n_columns);
    for(int i = 0; i < m1.n_rows; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < m1.n_columns; j++) {
        newMat.arr[i][j] = m1.arr[i][j] * m2.arr[j][i];
      }
    }
    return newMat;
  }
};
```

/***Here i used a c++ file to run a the header file but the message " fatal error : Matrix.h: no such file or directory"  was shown in the build messages, How do i run the header file using this program?***/

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"
using namespace std;


int columns, rows;

void printMatrix(Matrix mat){
  cout << "[ ";
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    cout << "[ ";
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      cout << mat.arr[i][j] << ", ";
    }
    cout << " ], ";
  }
  cout << " ]" << endl;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling it? It works fine in [online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/XHEqgJ)

Comment: the first part of the code you give is not in the file Matrix.h ? What do you mean by "run the header file" ?

Comment: Why do you write everything fat and cursive? And what did you expect to happen? Do you know that you need a `main`-function as entry point? Because I don't see any.

Comment: why *printMatrix* is not a member of the class ? why the attributes of the class are  public ? why *columns* and *rows* are global ?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, you have a memory leak in your class, your destructor should iterate over `arr` and invoke `delete[]` on each row (just like you did with `new` in the constructor) followed by the `delete[]` on `arr` itself.

Comment: Obviously the problem is that you haven't put the header file in the right place, or you haven't told the compiler how to find it. In other words this a using the compiler issue, not a C++ language issue. Since you haven't said which compiler you are using it's hard to help. I suggest you find someone locally who can show you how to use whatever compiler you are using.

Comment: Also, until you are familiar with how to use your compiler I would suggest you write much simpler programs that this one. Currently you have multiple issues. So you should try easy things first so you only have to deal with one issue at a time.

Comment: Create a Matrix.h file for definition of the matrix class and Matrix.cc should be used for defining the implementation.Get number of row and columns from the user and store them n  Rows and n Columns variables.Define a matrix class with n Rows X n Columns dimensions using dynamic memory allocation in the constructor.  Constructor also should initialize each element in the matrix to a random integer value between -50 and +50.Implement the overload operator for matrix addition, subtraction multiplication.
Implement the destructor. Show the program is working using a test program.ITS THE PRBLM?

Answer (score 2):

> Here i have created a header file to implement matrix representation.But The file doesn't compile

do not compile a header file (extension h / hh), compile source files (extension c / cc /cpp ...)

> Matrix.h: no such file or directory

that means the compiler does not find your header file, if you do not put both files in the same directory you need to indicate how to find the header file. The way to do depends on the compiler / IDE you use

---

Out of that several remarks can be done :

*printMatrix* is typically a member of your class, to have it as a function you need to access to the internal members of your class, for that they are public which is a bad idea.

This function also use the variables *columns* and *rows* and these ones are global, this is also a bad idea, move them local to the function (or better the method of the class)

When you print the content of the array there is an extra ',' after the last element / last dimension, this is not very pretty

You have memory leaks because your destructor only delete the global array but not the sub arrays

In your operators +/-/* you suppose *m2* has the same dimensions or more than *m1*, if this is not the case you read out of your arrays with an undefined behavior

In your constructor you do two *for* but all can be done in only one

Of course a *main* is missing to produce an executable and run it

Comment: You are talking to someone who doesn't know the difference between compiling code and running code and also doesn't know the simplest thing about using their compiler correctly. Do you think the above advice is going to be of any help?

Comment: @john yes if I answer this is hopping that helps, when you answer yourself this is not with the same hope ? :-) "who doesn't know the difference between compiling code and running code" I was first thinking as you, but may be be the OP just do not use the right words even he understands ? May be I am too optimistic, but why not ?